# Usage of 向こう in this sentence

Tags: nuances, reading-comprehension

[image]

So the characters gets asked "how come you two are friends?" thus explaining that when they were kids, the other's person used to help him a lot.

Then he adds

だからって別に向こうも親友ってつもりもないだろうし

I am a bit unsure on how to take his answer.

"Even so, you wouldn't think of the other as your best friend because of that"?

Answer (score 2):

向こう refers to 'the other' and always third person. That is, it never means *you*. Relevant expressions: あっち can replace 向こう (and never means *you* either). そっち means *you* and never means third person in similar contexts.

So 向こう means the other in the context of the first two panels, meaning the friend of the speaker who helped him in childhood: *even then, I guess he didn't think we were best friends. That kind of thing is creepy*. (気持ち悪い is hard to translate)

Comment: Couldn't it be "I didn't believe the other was s best friend '

Comment: @Kawase_K The subject of つもり is 向こう（も）.  向こうも親友ってつもりはない would be more accurately *He does not think he's the best friend of mine*, and だろう adds *I guess*.